# Setting regex options in R

Tags: regex, r

The documentation for `regex`, R version 3.1.2, states that

> Perl-like matching can work in several modes, set by the options (?i)
>   (caseless, equivalent to Perl's /i), (?m) (multiline, equivalent to
>   Perl's /m), (?s) (single line, so a dot matches all characters, even
>   new lines: equivalent to Perl's /s) and (?x) (extended, whitespace
>   data characters are ignored unless escaped and comments are allowed:
>   equivalent to Perl's /x). These can be concatenated, so for example,
>   (?im) sets caseless multiline matching.

However, I'm unable to use those options, except for `(?i)` without getting an error:

```
my.str <- "Abc
abc
ABC"

grep(pattern = "(?mi)abc", x = my.str)
```

For the placement of the option in the regex, I tried both at the beginning and end with the same results. Any idea how to make options other than `(?i)` work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `perl=TRUE`: `grep(pattern = "(?mi)abc", x = my.str, perl = TRUE)`. Have a look at http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/grep.html.

> The regular expressions used are those specified by POSIX 1003.2,
>   either extended or basic, depending on the value of the extended
>   argument, unless perl = TRUE when they are those of PCRE,
>   http://www.pcre.org/. (The exact set of patterns supported may depend
>   on the version of PCRE installed on the system in use, if R was
>   configured to use the system PCRE. R's internal copy used PCRE 6.7.)

Answer (score 1):

The most advantageous way to use regular expressions with R is to pass the `perl=TRUE` parameter. This tells R to use the [**PCRE**](http://www.pcre.org/) library. As stated in the R [**Documentation**](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) ...

> The perl = TRUE argument to grep, regexpr, gregexpr, sub, gsub and strsplit switches to the **PCRE** library that implements regular expression pattern matching using the same syntax and semantics as Perl 5.x, with just a few differences.

```
grep('(?mi)abc', my.str, perl = TRUE)
```

Comment: Now I'm curious what the "few differences" are. In the last line of the quote, *...using the same syntax and semantics as Perl 5.x, with just a few differences.*